# How to read root attribute by XPath in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Stock Date="13.11.2013 11:14:13">
      <Assortment>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Item>NNNNNNNNNNNN</Item>
        <Quantity>12</Quantity>
      </Assortment>
    </Stock>
```

My code is

```
     System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
     doc.Load(LocalPath);
     dat = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Stock/@Date").Value;
```

How to read Date attribute of Stock in XPath?

Comment: Your solution works as is, I copied to VS and works, dat gets "13.11.2013 11:14:13", are you loading the correct file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need the **root** element, I wouldn't go with XPath. XPath is for finding something without knowing its location inside your XML tree (DOM). You could try something like this.

```
// Load the document and set the root element.
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(LocalPath);
XmlNode rootNode = doc.DocumentElement;
var dat = rootNode.Attributes["Date"].Value;
```

You could see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for XML DOM parsing, and then using XPath.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.Load(LocalPath);
var dat = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Stock/@Date");
```

Comment: See my updated answer. it is working :). Please make a vote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at linkToXml (Systme.xml.linq), its a really nice clean easy way of parsing xml, here's the alternative to the above

```
 var doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
 doc.Root.Attributes().ToList().ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a));
 doc.Root.Descendants().Where(d => d.Name.LocalName == "Item").ToList().ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a));
```

output:
    Date="13.11.2013 11:14:13"
    NNNNNNNNNNNN

Comment: Output is this:
    Date="13.11.2013 11:14:13"
    <Item>NNNNNNNNNNNN</Item>